# Fill gaps in piped in audio with silence in FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

So I'm using FFMPEG to receive audio through stdin and redirect it to a file. The audio is in realtime, so I'm using the `-re` flag on the input to tell FFMPEG to read it in realtime.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes the audio cuts out, so no data will be piped to stdin. How can I make FFMPEG fill this time with silence so that it doesn't stop and start again?

I've tried using the `aresample=async=1` filter on the output, but I think that's only for audio and video syncing.

The command I'm using at the moment is `ffmpeg -hide_banner -f FORMAT -ac CHANNELS -ar SAMPLERATE -re -i pipe:0 -af aresample=async=1 -y output.mp3`, where the channels, format and sample rate are set depending on whatever the format of the input is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aresample=async=1` is the correct filter but it relies on the timestamps of the received audio being accurate in terms of their temporal position. You seem to be receiving a raw feed which has no timestamps, so ffmpeg assigns sequential timestamps irrespective of when the audio packet is received. So there are no gaps for aresample to plug.

Add `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps true` as an input option. FFmpeg will get system time and assign that at time of receiving a packet.